# Loop quits after one iteration

Tags: arrays, loops, iteration

I have the following loop:

```
    public int getIsRepeated(int index)
    {
        long currentValue = myValues[index - 1];
        long previousValue = myValues[index - 2];

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = index - 5; i >= 4; i =- 4) 
        {
            if (myValues[i] == currentValue && myValues[i - 1] == previousValue)
                count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

The table is populated with numbers, where number can repeat in batches of 4, for example:

```
        myValues[1] = 29;
    myValues[2] = 12;
    myValues[3] = 144;
    myValues[4] = 123;
    myValues[5] = 234;
    myValues[6] = 348;
    myValues[7] = 666;
    myValues[8] = 333;
    myValues[9] = 100;
    myValues[10] = 500;
    myValues[11] = 666;
    myValues[12] = 333;
    myValues[13] = 100;
    myValues[14] = 500;
    myValues[15] = 666;
    myValues[16] = 333;
    myValues[17] = 100;
    myValues[18] = 500;
    index= 19;
```

The function should start checking for duplicate values and starts from index 14 and 13 and compares them with indexes 18 and 17 respectively. The loop should then iterate one other time to compare the values at index 10 and 9, but it exits after one iteration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you going down in fours? If the numbers are related somehow put them in a composite type (object) and have an array of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an error:

```
for (int i = index - 5; i >= 4; i =- 4)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = index - 5; i >= 4; i -= 4)
```

Comment: arrghh small typo with negative side-effectss